# How do I automatically Start the timer when I reload this Page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, timer

```
<p id="countdown"></p>
  <div id="startButtons">
    <button onclick="sample()" id="gameStart" class="gameStart">LETS GO!</button>

    <script>
      var timeleft = 90;
      window.onload = timedText;
      function sample() {
        document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = "<style>.paragraph(visibility:collapse);";
        document.getElementById('gameStart').innerHTML = "<style>.gameStart(visibility:collapse);";
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function
          function1() {
          document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + "&nbsp" + "seconds left";

          timeleft -= 1;
          if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);

            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "The time has ended!";

            window.open("index2.1.html");
          }
        }, 1000);

        console.log(countdown)

      }

    </script>
```

I making this game of words and I don't really get how to start the timer when I reload the page, I want the timer to start by itself, So if I click Enter on the home page and reach this page the timer should start by itself..., and when the timer gets finished another window should open that is the 2.1 index.html
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than wrapping your JavaScript loop up in a function that needs to be called on page load, just run the JavaScript directly (without placing in a function) and the page will run it as soon as it reads/loads it.

```html
<p id="countdown">Countdown Beginning</p>

<script>
  var timeleft = 90;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = `${timeleft} seconds left`;
    timeleft -= 1;
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "The time has ended!";
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: The code works but when the time ends the page doesn't change, can you help me with that

Comment: adding your `window.open("index2.1.html")` back in should work ‍♂️